# How to call and SMS from Android smartphone with SIM via internet remotely?

Tags: sim-card, voip, gsm, gateway

I want to use my phone number when traveling abroad and there is no possibility to setup roaming, etc. So the idea is: I have Android smartphone. I have my SIM inserted in the phone.

The phone works as usual phone - it is turned on and connected to charger. I need software that is capable to answer for incoming phone calls and relay the call via internet to some other phone or PC with corresponding software that runs on it. That is when somebody calls me, my phone that is turned on in my home answers to call, transfer the call/voice via internet to another country where I obtain some signal to my second phone or PC and can have a conversation.

I have VOIP phone number but this doesn't solve the issue - I need exactly the phone number bound to my physical SIM - some services verify that number is virtual and do not work with such numbers. Could you please suggest Android application that solve the issue.

**Updated:**
I've fount following article related to question. What do you think about it?
[Using Android phone as GSM Gateway for VoIP](https://www.ictinnovations.com/using-android-phone-as-gsm-gateway)